# A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown AWS Create DB Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

In .NET i am working with RDS Mysql . When :

```
                CreateDBInstanceRequest instancia = new CreateDBInstanceRequest();
            instancia.DBInstanceIdentifier = "instancia_desde_c";
            instancia.DBInstanceClass = "db.t2.micro";
            instancia.AllocatedStorage = 5;
            instancia.DBName = "db_from_c";
            instancia.DBSecurityGroups.Add("default");
            instancia.Engine = "MySQL";
            instancia.EngineVersion = "5.6.27";
            instancia.MasterUsername = "info";
            instancia.MasterUserPassword = "gdgjkljalkjs12";

            Console.WriteLine("Enviando Solicitud para la creación de la instancia : " + instancia.DBName);
            CreateDBInstanceResponse respuesta = RDSClient.CreateDBInstance(instancia);
            Console.WriteLine("Instancia DB {0} Creada", instancia.DBName);
```

In visual studio 2012 :

A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown

"Connection Refused"